# How to get rid of sudo creep for btrfs commands?

Tags: btrfs

Until recently, I was able to run btrfs commands without the sudo prefix. Things like `btrfs subvolume list /home` would work.

But I issued one command with `sudo` (I think for creating a snapshot). Now I have to use `sudo` with every command.

I tried making sure that all the subvolumes have correct non-root ownership (user & group), but still I have to use `sudo`

What else may have changed? How can I fix this?